# VS 2013 Extending: managing class from an item

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, vs-extensibility

What I'm trying to do it's, i think, kinda complex, but i've spent hours trying to find the right documentation, about the interfaces I need to achieve this with no luck:
I need VS write some javascript code and insert it in a certain folder, starting from:

- Right click action, on a file from an already created project.
- A window it's open that gets information about the functions from
  that class in that file that i've right clicked. Besides, it should
  have a dropdown, with all the names of classes that reside under a
  certain folder.
- If I select an item from this dd and press the "ok" button, the IDE
  should write some code, using the properties of this selected class,
  and the functions from the right-clicked file, as information, to
  create the javascript file and save it into the project on a certain
  folder of it.

I've achieved some parts of this process:

- I know how to create an option into a context menu, using the
  initialize function.
- Partially, I know how to create new files in a project.
- I know how to create a window tool and almost all the interfaces that
  are needed for what I want to achieve (make dropdowns and that kind
  of stuff).

But the critical part is managing the already created classes and gather info from them in the manner I need.

Comment: Side note: VS2015 with Roslyn would likely be much easier (with plenty of samples - like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn904670.aspx)

Comment: Thank you @AlexeiLevenkov. Unfortunately, I've limited infrastructure to migrate to VS2015 (explicitly ram) and i'm using MVC5. I'm not so sure if I edit my VS2013 project  on a VS2015 will do a clean migration of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio [Code Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228763%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) to gather info from existing classes.